# How can I activate a Panel-icon via a script (or get its screen co-ordinates; to click it)?

Tags: xorg, bash

This question is in the context of Lucid 10.04 desktop (ie. no Unity).

I do most screen navigation via the keyboard (not the mouse), so I'm looking for a script solution to re-activating an app which has been "minimized" to the Panel's Notification Area.

I'll use **Skype** as an example.

`wmctrl` allows me enough access to normally-minimized windows, but when Skype is "minimized" to the Notification Area, it simply goes "off the radar" as far as **wmctrl** is concerned.

Bearing in mind that icon positions in the Notification Area can vary, is there some way to determine the screen co-ordinates of Skype's Panel icon, so I can "click" it using `xdotool` (or a similar utility)?

...or maybe there is a more direct way to activate the "dormant" Skype? ... (and I don't mean the mouse ;)

Here is the script, so far. Hopefully it will make clear what I'm trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
procname="skype-wrapper"
windmask="Skype™"
if [[ $(pgrep -x -n -c "$procname") == 1 ]] ; then 
  wintitle="$(wmctrl -l |grep "$windmask" |head -n 1 |sed -n "s/^.\+${HOSTNAME} \(.*\)/\1/p")"
  if [ "$wintitle" = "" ] ; then
    echo "Click on Skype's Panel-icon to show the main window"  
    ###############################################################
    # How can I find the screen co-ordinates of Skype's Panel Icon
    ###############################################################
  else
    # Skype is running, and has (at least) one visible window which matches $windmask. Activate it.
   wmctrl -a "$wintitle"
  fi
else 
  # The process is not currently running. Start it.
  ("$procname" &)
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://d01.megashares.com/dl/161a012/Skype.zip

- zskypewrapper.sh is my custom script to show Skype (@fred.bear, for right or wrong, I just 'wmctrl -a Skype™' to show an already-existing window).
- showskype.py is ændrük's script above, modified to also print Skype's return code.
- Skype.desktop is a .desktop file I created for use with Docky, which is the whole reason I wrote zskypewrapper.sh (but zskypewrapper will work without the .desktop, and I even threw in some logic which is only useful from the command-line and Docky never can use).  This .desktop is not needed, per se; all I did was nautilus->right-click->create launcher and put in zskypewrapper.sh.

zskypewrapper.sh and showskype.py need to be executable and in $PATH somewhere.

Hope this helps someone.  :-D

Comment: Thanks zpletan (and of course, ændrük)... This is definitely the best way for Skype...  The method I described (in my answer) works well enough for 'not directly' controlable panel icons, but it has associated constraints, like: Changing the Panel's colour scheme requires resetting it, and it doesn't work when a full screen app hides the panel, and Skype was a pain to set up, because of all the different status icons it uses... Now, with your Skype solution, its all fair weather sailing !

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import dbus

# Get a D-Bus interface to Skype
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
skype_object = bus.get_object('com.Skype.API', '/com/Skype')
skype = dbus.Interface(skype_object, dbus_interface='com.Skype.API')

# Ask for permission to control Skype
response = skype.Invoke("NAME " + __file__)
response = skype.Invoke("PROTOCOL 8")

# Issue commands
response = skype.Invoke("SET WINDOWSTATE NORMAL")
```

It's not as generalized as you wanted, but it might get the job done. For anything other than simple personal use it will need some error handling added in.

Source: [Skype Public API Reference](http://developer.skype.com/accessories)

Comment: ændrük. It seems a good method forSkype, but I'm afraid it is a bit beyond me. I have minimal bash and  python knowledge, so when it failed on "skype_object = ...", and my skype --help does not list the "--enable-dbus --use-system-dbus" options, and I see things in the "public_api_ref" like *"Important: The Skype for Linux API, version 1.3, beta uses D-BUS version .23. The next release will move to support for D-BUS version .61+"*. Ubuntu's  dbus version is 1.2.16-2. It seems that the best thing I can do is have a cup of coffee... Thanks. (I might scan for unique pixel groups; easier :)

Comment: Yikes, looks like old documentation. `--enable-dbus --use-system-dbus` shouldn't be necessary, and apparently this only works *after* you have signed in to Skype.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to put together a python script which does the job (... a big learning curve, and a good way to learn :)

It won't make it to mainstream, but I'm posting it for anyone who may be interested.

Because there is no way I know of to directly determine the co-ordinates of a particular Notification-Tray icon, I've had to "search" for the icon.

To identify an icon, the script has a "one time per icon" CAPTURE proc, which identifies a (hopefully) unique row of pixels... fortunately icons are very multi-coloured.
(the capture proc calls on 2 minor bash scripts)

I'm not sure what the **askubuntu** policy is regarding a large code posting, so until I find out if it is Okay or not, I've posted it to *pastebin.ubuntu.com*

The main script is 140 lines of actual code, but runs to 240 with coments, and for some unknown reason, when in the **pastebin**, many but not all of the lines are double-spaced, pushing it to 339! (my editor is set to Unix LF)...

Here are the links to the main python scripts and the 2 helper bash scripts;

- [find.and.click.pane.icon.py](http://paste.ubuntu.com/541689/)
- [coordinates.screen.rectangle.sh](http://paste.ubuntu.com/541684/)
- [coordinates.screen.point.sh](http://paste.ubuntu.com/541680/)

Comment: I'm getting more impressed by your ability to learn things every day. Fantastic stuff, keep it coming!